# Bootstrap image gallery, failing to show starting controls

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-image-gallery

I am using [bootstrap image gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery) (by blueimp) to enhance my images in bootstrap. I followed the tutorial outlined in the demo part from the repo and was able to get a nicely looking gallery.

I modified it a little bit to get rid of modal dialog (as in author's [borderless example](http://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/)). Everything works almost perfect (here is my [simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2PcjY/)). The only problem is that I have no controls when I just click on a small preview. Only when I click later on the original image - controls appear on the screen.

I assume that I am missing something really simple, like `showStartingControlls = true;` :-), but I can not figure this out.

Would be very grateful if someone can look into this problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The doc** : https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/blob/master/README.md#controls

Just add the `blueimp-gallery-controls` class.

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/PrHVb/

**HTML** :

```
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-use-bootstrap-modal="false">
```